# Is there no blocking mechanism in msgsnd? Message Queues: IPC

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue, blocking, nonblocking

In C interprocess communication,  we have the option to invoke msgrcv either as a blocking call or a non blocking call. But it seems msgsnd does not have the same flexibility.

I tried to use

```
msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&my_message, MAX_TEXT, IPC_NOWAIT)
```

but it behaves exactly the same way as

```
msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&my_message, MAX_TEXT, 0)
```

What I was expecting that

```
msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&my_message, MAX_TEXT, 0)
```

will be blocked until there is someone receiving on the other end. However it proceeds to the next line in the code even if there is no receive function on the other side. 
I do not understand why.

So is there no blocking mechanism in msgsend at all?

Comment: Perhaps msgsnd() failed for some reson - you should check the return value of msgsnd(), and the inspect errno if msgsnd() returned -1 to learn why it failed.

Comment: No, msgsnd() does not fail. I know this because I checked the message queue right after my code processes by ipcs -q. The messages were there.

Comment: and I did inspect the return value. It was 0 in both cases. This was also an indication that message went through successfully.

Comment: Why *would* a write block waiting for a read? Does writing to a memory location block until that memory is read again? Does writing a file block until the file is read again? Does writing to a non-full pipe block until it is read? No. Writes are ideally a pure sink, creating no other dependencies for the writer (and much complexity ensures whenever that is not true).

Comment: Well, it is a queue. It has room to queue a certain amount of data, so if the queue is not full, sending on it does not block - so you're simply not exceeding the queue limit.

Comment: @EOF Well. In this case, the point is not write. My objective is to be sure that the message has been received by the other side.

Comment: @HarisGhauri: That sort of think would just be asking for deadlock if the write blocked.

Comment: Not necessarily. Deadlock just means the queue is full and msgsnd should fail. But my point is that the sender process should be able to confirm that the receiver has received the message just like it happens in the receiver's case.. Well, fair enough, I have got my answer. There is no such way, i guess.